# Find last occurrence of unique values in a column and alter value in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame as below

```
a  b
5  0
5  0
5  0
6  0
6  0
```

I require to edit the column `b` and change it to one, at the last instance of each unique value of `a`. Example expected output is,

```
a  b
5  0
5  0
5  1
6  0
6  1
```

I'm looking for an efficient solution than using `apply()` to extract the row number and then traverse the dataframe to change the value, as my dataframe is large in size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple ways to do this

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(a) %>%
  mutate(b = if_else(row_number() == n(), 1L ,b))

#     a     b
#  <int> <dbl>
#1     5     0
#2     5     0
#3     5     1
#4     6     0
#5     6     1
```

---

Same using `ave`

```
with(df, ave(b, a, FUN = function(x) ifelse(seq_along(x) == length(x), 1, x)))
```

---

**EDIT**

In case if you have columns as characters, we need to convert them to numeric first and use `if_else`

```
df %>%
  mutate_all(as.numeric) %>%
  group_by(a) %>%
  mutate(b = if_else(row_number() == n(), 1 ,b))
```

OR just use `ifelse` as it does not depend on strict type checking

```
df %>%
  group_by(a) %>%
  mutate(b = ifelse(row_number() == n(), 1 ,b))
```

Comment: I'm getting the error: `false` has type 'character' not 'integer' , when I run the command

Comment: @Visahan Seems you have `b` as character, oyou need to convert it to numeric or just use  `ifelse` then , `df %>%
  group_by(a) %>%
  mutate(b = ifelse(row_number() == n(), 1 ,b))
`

Answer (score 2):

Use `duplicated` and set `fromLast` to be `TRUE` so that you start looking from the end of `a`.

```
with(df1, replace(b, !duplicated(a, fromLast = TRUE), 1))
#[1] 0 0 1 0 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but if you don't mind, could you provide a brief description of the equation? It will be really helpful

Comment: Though this command sets the value '1' in the correct rows, all the 0's are changed to NA. I know I can use 'df1$b[is.na(df1$b)] <- 0' to set them back to 0, but it seems inefficient.

Comment: I didn't see you used `duplicated`.  You can make it compact to `as.integer(!duplicated(df1$a, fromLast = TRUE))`

Comment: @Visahan This variant might be clearer? `transform(df1, b = replace(b, !duplicated(a, fromLast=TRUE), 1))` You can read `?duplicated`, `?replace`, `?transform` etc

Answer (score 1):

You could do a join on the last row:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DT)

DT[.(unique(a)), on=.(a), mult="last", b := 1]

   a b
1: 5 0
2: 5 0
3: 5 1
4: 6 0
5: 6 1
```

The syntax is `x[i, on=, j]`.

- It looks up each row of `i` in `x` using join conditions `on=`.
- When there are multiple matches for a row of `i`, it takes the last one.
- In `j`, we are updating `b` in `x` on the matched rows.